# Implicit cast from const string to bool

Tags: c++, g++, g++4.9

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(bool a)
{
        std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
}

void foo(long long int a)
{
        std::cout << "long long int" << std::endl;
}

void foo(const std::string& a)
{
        std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
        foo("1");
        return 0;
}
```

When executing I get this output:

```
bool
```

I would have expected as output:

```
string
```

Why does g++ 4.9 implicitly cast this string to bool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler is interpreting the standard correctly. Yes, this is a tricky corner case that many interviewers ask so they appear smarter than they really are.

The route `const char[2]` (the formal type of the literal `"1"`) to `const char*` to `bool` is a *standard conversion sequence*, since it uses exclusively built-in types.

Your compiler *must* favour that to a *user-defined conversion sequence*, viz. the `std::string` constructor from a `const char*`.

The presence of the overload `void foo(long long int a)` is a red herring.

You can rather elegantly work around this in C++11 by dropping your overload to `bool`, and writing

```
#include <type_traits>
template <
    typename Y,
    typename T = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Y, bool>{}>
>
void foo(Y)
{
  std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
}
```

in its place. The compiler will then favour the `std::string` for `const char[N]` over the template (as that is one of the requirements of overload resolution). Nice!

Answer (score 1):

"1" is a string literal, that is array of `char` that gets converted to pointer and then to `bool`. Notice that this path is preferred to implicit construction of a temporary `std::string` object.

Answer (score 1):

`"1"` is a string literal, which - when used as function argument - decays to a pointer of type `const char*`. As there is no overload for function `foo` taking a `const char*`, but there is a standard conversion from `const char*` to `bool`, it falls back to `foo(bool)`. Note that a pointer value, when taken as a bool argument, is interpreted like `somePtr==nullptr ? false : true`.