# Why does my variant convert a std::string to a bool?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

My `std::variant` can be empty (`std::monostate`), contain an `int`, a `std::string` or a `bool`.

When I want to feed it with a string, given as `var = "this is my string"`, it gets converted to a `bool` and not to a string. If I declare the type explicitly, it works `var = std::string("this is my string")`. Why is that and is there something I can to do avoid it?

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using var = std::variant<std::monostate, int, std::string, bool>;

    var contains_nothing;    
    var contains_int = 5;
    var contains_string = "hello";
    var contains_expl_string = std::string("explicit hello");
    var contains_bool = false;

    auto visitor = [](auto&& arg){
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::monostate>())
                std::cout<<"nothing\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>())  
                std::cout<<"int: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>())  
                std::cout<<"string: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>())  
                std::cout<<"bool: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else 
                std::cout<<"Visitor is not exhaustive\n";
        };

    std::visit(visitor, contains_nothing);       // nothing
    std::visit(visitor, contains_int);           // int: 5
    std::visit(visitor, contains_string);        // bool: 1
    std::visit(visitor, contains_expl_string);   // string: explicit hello
    std::visit(visitor, contains_bool);          // bool: 0    
}
```

**EDIT**
Since users of my code might not explicitly make `string`s, I like to catch that. Otherwise it would be a source of error. I made template-helper function that checks if a `char*` has been passed and if so, makes a std::string. Works well. Help for making this simpler is appreciated!

**EDIT 2**
By declaring `std::monostate` as default parameter/type, it even works when `make_var` is called without any argument.

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

using var = std::variant<std::monostate, int, std::string, bool>;

template<typename T = std::monostate>
var make_var(T value = std::monostate())
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type, const char*>())
        return std::string(value);
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    auto contains_nothing = make_var();    
    auto contains_int = make_var(3);
    auto contains_string = make_var("hello");
    auto contains_expl_string = make_var(std::string("excplicit hello"));
    var contains_bool = make_var(false);

    auto visitor = [](auto&& arg){
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
            if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::monostate>())
                std::cout<<"nothing\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>())  
                std::cout<<"int: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>())  
                std::cout<<"string: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>())  
                std::cout<<"bool: "<<arg<<"\n";
            else 
                std::cout<<"Visitor is not exhaustive\n";
        };

    std::visit(visitor, contains_nothing);
    std::visit(visitor, contains_int);
    std::visit(visitor, contains_string);
    std::visit(visitor, contains_expl_string);
    std::visit(visitor, contains_bool);    
}
```

Comment: Another question to ask is, why should `std::string` be preferred to `bool`? Both require array decay and type conversion.

Comment: See my lovely answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021989/implicit-cast-from-const-string-to-bool especially my workaround using a template ;-). But Angew's use of a user defined literal (below) is cuter.

Comment: short answer: it doesn't, because that's not an `std::string` you gave it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The type of `"hello"` is `const char [6]`, which decays to `const char *`. The conversion from `const char *` to `bool` is a built-in conversion, while the conversion from `const char *` to `std::string` is a user-defined conversion, which means the former is performed.

Since you're using C++ >= 14, you can use the literal suffix `s` to denote a `std::string` literal:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

var contains_string = "hello"s;
```

Comment: Why didn't it pick up the `int` type instead of `bool`?

Comment: @skypjack Because there is no implicit pointer to `int` conversion in C++.

Comment: It makes sense indeed. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Is there a possible fix to prevent conversion from `const char*` to `string` without the need to be explicit?

Answer (score 4):

`"hello"` isn't a `std::string`, it's a `const char *` and it can be implicitly converted to bool as well as used to construct a `std::string`.
In other terms, this works just fine:

```
int main() {
    bool b = "foo";
    (void)b;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @aschepler:

> The implicit conversion from `const char*` to `bool` is preferred over the user-defined conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`.  `int` is not an option at all.

Comment: No UB here.  The implicit conversion from `const char*` to `bool` is preferred over the user-defined conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`.  `int` is not an option at all.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you, fixed.