# Why is a const pointer accidentally converted to bool?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors, boolean-expression

I have a class with two constructors. One for `bool` and one for `A*`.

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(bool b)
    {
      std::cout << "B(bool)" << std::endl;
    }
    explicit B(A*)
    {
      std::cout << "B(A*)" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

When B should be constructed with `const A*` instead of `A*` -- `const A*` is converted to `bool`.

```
const A a;
B b(&a);
```

output: **`B(bool)`**

---

The desired solution would be a

> compiler error : "no valid constructor for B(const A*)"

I already tried with `explicit` keyword, but it did not work.

[running example at coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a3932536458eceb)

Comment: If you change `B(bool)` to `B(bool&)` then also the problem can be solved. Or consider using a type_trait as stated in the [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022072/514235).

Comment: thanks -- now I need to find all possible "traps" in our codebase

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate - the suggested duplicate has a `std::string` overload. This is very different - strings are not built-in types, and don't convert to `bool`. Pointers do.

Comment: @MSalters, it seems a duplicate because in the linked Qn, the OP is expecting `const char*` to get converted to `std::string`. Here it's `const A*`. You may also refer the super duplicate to the linked Qn. Refer OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372900/why-is-a-const-pointer-accidentally-casted-to-bool?noredirect=1#comment104939037_59372958), which tells that the linked answer satisfies the query.

Comment: @iammilind: But that's an entirely different rank of conversion.

Comment: at all -- for me it would be OK to go with the linked question -- it seems there is no better solution than in the linked answer and what @songyuanyao mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't stop the implicit conversion ([bool conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions)) from pointer to `bool`; You can add another overloaded constructor taking `const A*`, which will be selected in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) when passing `const A*`, because it's an exact match and `B::B(bool)` requires an implicit conversion. With marking it as [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions), the program becomes ill-formed if it's selected.

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(bool b)
    {
      std::cout << "B(bool)" << std::endl;
    }
    explicit B(A*)
    {
      std::cout << "B(A*)" << std::endl;
    }
    B(const A*) = delete;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l41kqdCkVazyjXil)

Or you can mark the overloaded constructor taking pointer types `delete`, then all the pointer type can't be passed to `B::B`, except `A*` for which the constructor is declared seperately like you've done.

```
template <typename T>
B(T*) = delete;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BXy9pmFOTqm3M8t5)

Comment: possible -- but is there also a solution where I can't accidentally forget all possible overloads?

Comment: @florgeng Answer revised. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes the linked answer fits to my question -- unfortunately -- thank you anyway

Comment: It might be useful to expand this answer by explaining overload resolution and implicit conversion sequences.

Comment: And you also need `explicit B(std::nullptr_t) : B((A*)nullptr) {}`. ;-)